# Looking for an elegant solution that avoid merging two dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask

I have a `dask dataframe df` that looks as follows:

```
Main_Author PaperID
A           X
B           Y
C           Z
```

I also have another `dask dataframe pa` that looks as follows:

```
PaperID  Co_Author
X        D
X        E
X        F
Y        A
Z        B
Z        D
```

I want a resulting dataframe that looks as follows:

```
Main_Author  Co_Authors   Num_Co_Authors
A            (D,E,F)      3
B            (A)          1
C            (B,D)        2
```

This is what I did:

```
df = df.merge(pa, on="PaperID")

df = df.groupby('Main_Author')['Co_Author'].apply(lambda x: tuple(x)).reset_index()

df['Num_Co_Authors'] = df['Co_Author'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
```

This works on small dataframes. However, since I am working with really large ones, it keeps getting killed. I believe it is because I am merging. Is there a more elegant way of getting the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to work with two large `DataFrame`s, then you could try to wrap this `merge` in [`dask.delayed`](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed.html#delayed)

- there's a terrific example of `dask.delayed` [here in the Dask docs](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed.html#example) or [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42597019/4057186)
- see Dask use cases [here](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/use-cases.html#overview)

Imports

```
from faker import Faker
import pandas as pd
import dask
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
import random
fake = Faker()
```

Generate dummy data  in order to get a large number of rows in each `DataFrame`

- Specify number of rows of dummy data to generate in each `DataFrame`

```
number_of_rows_in_df = 3000
number_of_rows_in_pa = 8000
```

Generate some big dataset using the [`faker`](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#basic-usage) library (per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49227910/4057186))

```
def create_rows(auth_colname, num=1):
    output = [{auth_colname:fake.name(),
               "PaperID":random.randint(1000,2000)} for x in range(num)]
    return output
df = pd.DataFrame(create_rows("Main_Author", number_of_rows_in_df))
pa = pd.DataFrame(create_rows("Co_Author", number_of_rows_in_pa))
```

Print first 5 rows of dataframes

```
print(df.head())
       Main_Author  PaperID
0   Kyle Morton MD     1522
1    April Edwards     1992
2  Rachel Sullivan     1874
3    Kevin Johnson     1909
4     Julie Morton     1635

print(pa.head())
        Co_Author  PaperID
0  Deborah Cuevas     1911
1     Melissa Fox     1095
2    Sean Mcguire     1620
3     Cory Clarke     1424
4     David White     1569
```

Wrap the `merge` operation in a helper function

```
def merge_operations(df1, df2):
    df = df1.merge(df2, on="PaperID")
    df = df.groupby('Main_Author')['Co_Author'].apply(lambda x: tuple(x)).reset_index()
    df['Num_Co_Authors'] = df['Co_Author'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
    return df
```

Dask approach - Generate final `DataFrame` using `dask.delayed`

```
ddf = dask.delayed(merge_operations)(df, pa)
with ProgressBar():
    df_dask = dask.compute(ddf)
```

Output of Dask approach

```
[                                        ] | 0% Completed |  0.0s
[                                        ] | 0% Completed |  0.1s
[                                        ] | 0% Completed |  0.2s
[                                        ] | 0% Completed |  0.3s
[                                        ] | 0% Completed |  0.4s
[                                        ] | 0% Completed |  0.5s
[########################################] | 100% Completed |  0.6s

print(df_dask[0].head())
      Main_Author                                          Co_Author  Num_Co_Authors
0  Aaron Anderson  (Elizabeth Peterson, Harry Gregory, Catherine ...              15
1    Aaron Barron  (Martha Neal, James Walton, Amanda Wright, Sus...              11
2      Aaron Bond  (Theresa Lawson, John Riley, Daniel Moore, Mrs...               6
3  Aaron Campbell  (Jim Martin, Nicholas Stanley, Douglas Berry, ...              11
4  Aaron Castillo  (Kevin Young, Patricia Gallegos, Tricia May, M...               6
```

Pandas approach - Generate final `DataFrame` created using Pandas

```
df_pandas = (merge_operations)(df, pa)

print(df_pandas.head())
      Main_Author                                          Co_Author  Num_Co_Authors
0  Aaron Anderson  (Elizabeth Peterson, Harry Gregory, Catherine ...              15
1    Aaron Barron  (Martha Neal, James Walton, Amanda Wright, Sus...              11
2      Aaron Bond  (Theresa Lawson, John Riley, Daniel Moore, Mrs...               6
3  Aaron Campbell  (Jim Martin, Nicholas Stanley, Douglas Berry, ...              11
4  Aaron Castillo  (Kevin Young, Patricia Gallegos, Tricia May, M...               6
```

Compare `DataFrame`s obtained using Pandas and Dask approaches

```
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
try:
    assert_frame_equal(df_dask[0], df_pandas, check_dtype=True)
except AssertionError as e:
    message = "\n"+str(e)
else:
    message = 'DataFrames created using Dask and Pandas are equivalent.'
```

Result of comparing two approaches

```
print(message)
DataFrames created using Dask and Pandas are equivalent.
```